# Migrating certificate services to Server 2008 R1

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, migration, ad-certificate-services

I am currently planning a move of an Active Directory Certificate Services CA from a soon to be decommissioned Server 2003 R2 Standard box to an existing Windows 2008 R1 Enterprise box.

This is not something I have done before, so I've been looking through relevant documentation to get an idea of what's required, before testing the process in a lab. The most reliable and complete source of information seems to be Microsoft's [Active Directory Certificate Services Migration Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126170(v=ws.10).aspx). However, it only covers scenarios involving a destination server running the R2 release of Windows Server 2008, and not "R1".

Can anyone offer any advice on whether the guide can still be followed as-is or whether the approach needs to be modified slightly? Does anyone know the reasoning behind only covering the R2 release as a destination server? Is it purely because Microsoft would expect users to be running R2? From what I've read so far, the guide is silent with regards to the omission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be the Windows 2008 R1 specific version of the guide: [Active Directory Certificate Services Upgrade and Migration Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742515(v=ws.10).aspx)